# Реализация сокета socket.io + node.js + php

Tags: php, node.js, сокет, socket.io

Я очень плох в сокетах и JS, поэтому прошу понимания))
Вдохновленный [этой](https://habr.com/company/skillbox/blog/413957/) статьей, решил попробовать написать подобное у себя. У меня есть PHP скрипт, который дергается через cron и обновляет БД. В связи с этим вопрос: можно ли из PHP скрипта отправить информацию в каком-либо формате в серверный node.js скрипт, для последующей передачи через сокет этой информации в клиент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
?>
```

> array (   'effective_url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
>   'response_code' => 302,   'connect_code' => 0,   'filetime' => -1,
>   'total_time' => 0.212348,   'namelookup_time' => 0.038296,
>   'connect_time' => 0.104144,   'pretransfer_time' => 0.104307,
>   'starttransfer_time' => 0.212077,   'redirect_time' => 0,
>   'redirect_count' => 0,   'size_upload' => 0,   'size_download' => 218,
>   'speed_download' => 1026,   'speed_upload' => 0,   'header_size' =>
>   307,   'request_size' => 103,   'ssl_verifyresult' => 0,
>   'ssl_engines' =>   array (
>       0 => 'dynamic',
>       1 => 'cswift',
>       2 => 'chil',
>       3 => 'atalla',
>       4 => 'nuron',
>       5 => 'ubsec',
>       6 => 'aep',
>       7 => 'sureware',
>       8 => '4758cca',   ),   'content_length_download' => 218,   'content_length_upload' => 0,   'content_type' => 'text/html',
>   'httpauth_avail' => 0,   'proxyauth_avail' => 0,   'num_connects' =>
>   1,   'os_errno' => 0,   'error' => '', )

[source](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-get.php)

Comment: Я хотел бы понять как node.js сервер должен обрабатывать, допустим, JSON массив данных от скрипта PHP и отправлять его через сокет клиенту. PHP отправку я могу реализовать, трудности с node.js стороной.

Comment: @AtCliff_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js

Comment: то есть node.js в любой момент времени может принять POST JSON и отправить его сокетом?

Comment: @AtCliff_ нужно использовать http://expressjs.com/